# Show the wedge product of two tori is not homotopy equivalent to a 2-manifold.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was doing a practice qualifying exam test and I was having trouble with the following question.  Show the wedge sum of two tori is not homotopy equivalent to a 2-manifold.  It seems obvious why it is true, but I am not sure how to prove it.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What's the wedge product? I only know wedge sum. I presume they're not the same but Google search is inconclusive.

Comment: They are identified at a point

Comment: i guess i mean wedge sum

Comment: You might try to show that the second homology of the wedge of two tori is not $\mathbf{Z}$

Comment: how would that prove it?

Comment: A manifold has homology $\mathbf{Z}$ in top dimension, so if they have different second homology then they can't be homotopic (since homotopy equivalent $\implies$ homology groups are the same)

Comment: Do you know how to prove a manifold has dimension 1 in top dimension?

Comment: This is true exactly when the manifold is *connected*...

Comment: Not off the top of my head; it follows from the existence of the fundamental class, which is in chapter 3 of Hatcher

Comment: Wait.  Isn't a Klein Bottle a manifold.  It has homology 0 in top dimension.

Comment: Shouldn't the statement be that a manifold has homology Z or 0 in top dimension?

Comment: Oops yeah it depends on orientability. I should wait until I'm rested to say things about math

Comment: Is it true that every connected n-manifold can be given a CW-complex structure with one n-cell?

Comment: Oops.  If you just use $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients, then the orientability condition goes away.

Answer (score 2):

For a manifold of dimension $d$, the rank of $H^0$ is the number of connected components and the rank of $H^d$ is the number of components which are compact and orientable. In particular $\dim H^d \leq \dim H^0$. (This is what several of the comments were getting at.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Noticing that $\chi(\mathbb{T} \vee \mathbb{T})=-1$, you only have to show that $\mathbb{T} \vee \mathbb{T}$ is not homotopic equivalent to the connected sum of three projective spaces (for example using homology groups).

Comment: Why could we exclude the cases of non-compact manifolds or compact manifolds with boundary?

Comment: The fundamental group of a non-compact manifold or of a compact manifold with boundary is necessarily free. On the other hand, $\pi_1(\mathbb{T} \wedge \mathbb{T}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^2 \ast \mathbb{Z}^2$ is not free.

Comment: Very nice, given the fact in your first sentence! But how do we see it?

Comment: **Erratum:** of course, in my previous comment, "manifold" should be replaced with "surface".

Comment: You can find a proof of the fact that the fundamental group of non-compact surface is free here: https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/on-subgroups-of-surface-groups/ (Property 2). For the fact that the fundamental group of a surface with boundary is free as well, just take a fundamental polygon $P$ defining your surface, and remove $n \geq 1$ points. Then, notice that the punctured surface deformation retracts to a graph, whose fundamental group is free.